# textfield update text programmatically with ng-model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've a html textfield associated with jQuery color picker in an edit form

```
<input type="text" class="colorpicker-default form-control" ng-model="data.color" />
```

the value in the textfield is set by the color picker, I do see that the classes get added like `ng-touched` but when i submit the form, all other values get submitted except this one.

is there a problem if the value was not input by the keyboard and set by the color picker?

**Edit:**
I just did a test, when I manually type in there, the data.color gets updated and submitted but not when value gets sets by the color picker

**Temporary Solution:**

programatically updating $scope.data.color

```
this.$scope.data.color = document.getElementById("color").value;
```

Comment: more context/code, please. view, controller, is within directive, etc.

Comment: Could you include the code for the color picker? Perhaps it is the one which should contain ng-model="data.color"

Comment: Either you should write a directive or find a directive that integrates with jquery color picker. The thing here is jquery color picker changes input outside the context of angular, hence you need to manual synchronize the model.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the bottom of the function that color picker is calling upon selection:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

It sounds like the color picker is not angular related, so angular needs to be updated to things which occur outside of its scope.